# Ruby capybara + selenium dont run browser

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara, poltergeist

I want to run selenium without opening a browser window, because there is a lot of data that should be parsed and its very slow.

I'm trying to use poltergeist (phantomjs) for it, but it still open the browser. Maybe you can help me to configure it?

Currently my config is:

```
Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.run_server = false
  config.default_driver = :poltergeist
end

Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
    profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
    profile['browser.download.folderList'] = 2
    profile['browser.download.dir'] = RESULT_FOLDER

    profile['download.prompt_for_download'] = false
    profile['download.default_directory'] = RESULT_FOLDER
    profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = 'application/pdf'
    profile['pdfjs.disabled'] = true
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new( app, browser: :firefox, :profile => profile )
  end
```

I dont want to use webkit because it requires a running server.
Also can you help me with advice how to reach maximum performance with this stuff?

Comment: Why are you registering poltergeist as a driver and then telling it to run Firefox? PhantomJS is a separate binary and doesn't have anything to do with Firefox.

Comment: Ok, but when I do this one:
`Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
        Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app,
                                      :phantomjs_options => ['--local-storage-path=/home/extazystas/Downloads', '--debug=no', '--load-images=no', '--ignore-ssl-errors=yes', '--ssl-protocol=TLSv1'], :debug => false)
      end`
Browser doesn't run, but I can't find downloaded files.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a gem [headless](https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/headless) which can help you to do what you want or there is another solution that is [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org), there is even gem [phantomjs-gem](https://github.com/colszowka/phantomjs-gem)

Comment: Can I download files in specific folder with headless gem?

Comment: You can still use firefox as you did before, headless it only the way to use Xvfb